# Proving that a doubly stochastic matrix is a convex combination of permutation matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, graph-theory, permutations, stochastic-matrices

This is a homework problem in my graph theory class and I wanted tips on how to solve it. Any tips would be appreciated..

Show that any doubly stochastic matrix is a convex combination of permutation matrices, i.e. any double stochastic A can be written as
A=t<sub>1</sub>P<sub>1</sub> +t<sub>2</sub> +⋯t<sub>l</sub>P<sub>l</sub>,
where each P<sub>i</sub> is a permutation matrix, and the numbers t<sub>i</sub>  satisfy t<sub>1</sub>, . . . , t<sub>l</sub> ≥ 0 and ∑<sup>l</sup><sub>i=1</sub> t<sub>i</sub> = 1.

Comment: What you're trying to prove is known as the [Birkhoff-von Neumann theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix#Birkhoff_polytope_and_Birkhoff%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem). The standard proof of this uses [Hall's matching theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem).  Have you covered Hall's matching theorem in your graph theory class?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was able to figure it out!